# what is the filename.js?m=1497883755 in script attachment src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, magento, minifiedjs

I am facing a issue to rectify a jQuery file.

It's integration code is like this below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/global.footc75d.js?m=1497883755"></script>
```

my question is what is the "**.js?m=1497883755**" in this? what is the use of this..? why it was used this way not normally..?

and this one is looking like this below in the chrome browser > Developer tool > Network tab.

[image]

Requested to share the full detail about it. Why this was used this way..? not just by file name only..? should I use the same way in the future if yes then which condition..?? and how to edit the code in this condition.. how do I find and remove the code which is loading loader_light.gif here..?

Thanks to all in anticipate..

Comment: `?m=1497883755` is a cache buster

Comment: It's a timestamp to prevent caching. The additional querystring will make no difference to the content, so the 404 is because the file is not at the location you're calling, not because of the additional data in the URL.

Comment: For the duplicate: see the 2nd answer.

Comment: Don't thinks so that the question is the exact duplicate of any question. Since, I googled for the solution and nothing found only after I raised the question here.. nowhere see the same question with the image like the above of mine.